# からは meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 町内会**からは**ちびっこ店長**と親しまれる**謎の中国人・魃さんの振るう十字鍋は、ありとあらゆる食材を唐辛子まみれにする。

My TL:
The Cross-shaped pot that Batsu-san, a mysterious Chinese man from the neighborhood association who is known as "The little manager", wields fills every ingredient with chilli pepper.

FL:
The manager, a favourite of the neghbourhood association, is a strange little man known as "Small Manager". Batsu-san has a tendency to fill every dish with pepper.

I do not understand からは and と親しまれる.
Where does "a favourite of" come from in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[親]{した}しまれる is a passive form of [親]{した}しむ "be familiar with."  (親しまれる may be better translated as "be popular" or as you suggested, "be favored by")

からは is sort of an emphatic form of から "from", or in this context, "by."

Comment: So と親しまれる does not mean known as? I can't find online a sentence with 親しまれる= Be favored by.  
Can you make a gramatical analysis of this sentence?

Comment: It can be translated as "known as XYZ" *if* XYZ is a favorable word like the above "the little manager." First, throw away your illusion that you can establish one-to-one mapping between two different languages.
http://www.kirin.co.jp/customer/bi-ru3/tisiki_07.html 世界で親しまれるビール "Beer: the world's favorite" http://www.lifehacker.jp/2015/01/150105book_to_read.html 嫌われない人、親しまれる人に共通する話し方 "the way of speech common to those who don't make enemies and those who are favored"

Comment: Ah, perhaps you missed the fact と alone can work as として which unambiguously means "as".

Comment: から means by with the passive. I am so used to に that I forgot about that.  Also did not know about と which could mean として.

Comment: It's rather like quotative と but certainly should be translated into "as" in this passage.